# Omnet++ - Ethernet packet, unknow protocol

Tags: omnet++, ethernet, inet

im trying to build a network where the nodes communicate using Ethernet. My plan is to create a message which will be used in multiple simple modules inside the nodes and pass that information to a inet::Packet and send it between the nodes. So, im first trying to understand how to use the communication protocol by implementing a simple network where one of the nodes creates a packet and the other receives it. Im amble to create the Packet but upon receiving it, the node informs that the protocol is unknown and drops it. I'm following the examples of the EtherTrafficGen.cc, EtherAppClient.cc in the inet folder and the Developer's Guide to try to implement it but i think im a bit lost.

The code for the packet creation is the following:

```
void masterDispatcher::initialize()
{
    // Message test that will be used in other modules
    Frame *test = new Frame;
    test->setTest(24);

    // Ethernet Packet
    inet::MacAddress destMACAddress;

    inet::Packet *datapacket = new inet::Packet("test", inet::IEEE802CTRL_DATA);

    // Data
    const auto& frame = inet::makeShared<EthernetFrame>();
    frame->setChunkLength(inet::B(1));
    frame->setTestEther(test->getTest());
    datapacket->insertAtBack(frame);

    // Header
    datapacket->addTagIfAbsent<inet::MacAddressReq>()->setDestAddress(destMACAddress.BROADCAST_ADDRESS);


    auto ieee802SapReq = datapacket->addTagIfAbsent<inet::Ieee802SapReq>();
    ieee802SapReq->setSsap(-1);
    ieee802SapReq->setDsap(-1);

    send(datapacket, "lowerLayerOut");

}
```

The network that im using is the one in the image: [Implemented Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgqAb.png). Similiar to the EtherHost of INET, llc is the EtherEncap and the eth is the IEthernetInterface. Can anyone give me some tips of how to use this protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly, you want to implement an application that is directly communicating using ethernet (and you do NOT want to use IP or UDP for whatever reason). You should take a look how for example`EtherAppClient` is implemented. Your code is almost right, but you should use a `Ieee8022LlcSocket` to send a packet from an application to the link layer directly.

https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/v4.2.0/src/inet/applications/ethernet/EtherAppClient.cc#L185

The ISO layers inside a host are using protocol IDs for properly routing the packets. Protocol registration is handled by the `Ieee8022LlcSocket`. If you send the packet directly using `send`, the protocol id will not be filled and various issues will happen.

Generally, applications should *always* use sockets to communicate to/from lower OSI layers.

Comment: Thank you Rudi, i tried following the `EtherClient` example but it keeps saying that the protocol is unknown. I added a message dispatcher between the llc and simpleModule that produces the frames however i'm not sure if i need to use it since there is only one application. Nonetheless, when initiating the simulation it appears `handleMessage() unknown protocol` which is part of the MessageDispatcher. I think i may have missed a step  when putting the whole system together or the creating of the packets is wrong. The files im using are the following: https://imgur.com/a/2Nehwfh

Comment: * `EtherAppClient` i mean

Comment: After some testing i found out that the network required the `EtherAppServer` in order to receive the packets with the `MessageDispatcher`, the `EtherEncap` and `IEthernetInterface`, similar to the `EtherHost`.  My question is if it's possible to create a node that can receive and create ethernet packets with the same application without needing others, does it require both the `IEthernetInterface` and `EtherEncap` or can I simply connect a `IEthernetInterface` to my application similar to the `EtherHost2`?

Comment: Yes, check the Ieee8022LlcSocket API. You can send and receive on that interface. If your application implements the IApp interface, then you can add this app to any standard host (and that will still talk directly to the ethernet interface skipping the transport and network layer), so you don't even have to create your own Host type.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rudi, i will test it out and post questions if needed. For now i think i will consider this thread as solved.